# How do I "M-x replace-string" across all buffers in emacs?

Tags: emacs

How do I "M-x replace-string" across all buffers in emacs?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `ibuffer` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>

But you'll probably want to be a bit more restrictive than that, because it will abort if it can't do a replacement -- e.g. encounters a read-only dired buffer containing a matching filename.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> within ibuffer to read the mode help, and learn how to easily mark just the buffers you're interested in.

**Edit:** a non-regexp version of `ibuffer-do-replace-regexp` can easily be written by modifying the original definition:

```el
;; defines ibuffer-do-replace-string
(define-ibuffer-op replace-string (from-str to-str)
  "Perform a `replace-string' in marked buffers."
  (:interactive
   (let* ((from-str (read-from-minibuffer "Replace string: "))
          (to-str (read-from-minibuffer (concat "Replace " from-str
                                                " with: "))))
     (list from-str to-str))
   :opstring "replaced in"
   :complex t
   :modifier-p :maybe)
  (save-window-excursion
    (switch-to-buffer buf)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let ((case-fold-search ibuffer-case-fold-search))
        (while (search-forward from-str nil t)
          (replace-match to-str nil t))))
    t))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem completely equal to replace-string. r-s reads \ literally, U as regexp-syntax.

Comment: Very true, it's a regexp replace function, and there isn't a string variant built in, so you need to either deal with the regexps, or else you could define the analogous function. I'll add one to the answer.

Comment: Also, `M-x ibuffer RET t Q` will do the same interactively, giving you the chance to confirm each replacement.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of different choices, it kind of depends on how you want to do it.

Check out the Emacs Wiki for [SearchBuffers](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SearchBuffers).  Of interest would be moccur-edit and icicles.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Trey for mentioning [**Icicles** buffer searching](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview#toc5) in this regard.

Let me mention also <kbd>Q</kbd> (`dired-do-query-replace`) in Dired. Very handy. And be aware that you can easily mark sets of files in Dired using keys such as these (and there are more):

- <kbd>% m</kbd> (`dired-mark-files-regexp`) -- mark files whose names match a regexp
- <kbd>% g</kbd> (`dired-mark-files-containing-regexp`) -- mark files whose text (content) matches a regexp
- <kbd>* .</kbd> (`dired-mark-extension`) -- mark files whose names have the same extension (e.g., `.el`)

Be sure to load standard library `dired-x.el` (and perhaps `dired-aux.el`).

Answer (score 1):

I found this on a website some long time ago, sorry I don't remember the source.
If you find a read-only buffer, it will stop, so be careful.

Just place this in your .emacs

```
(defun query-replace-in-open-buffers (arg1 arg2)
  "query-replace in open files"
  (interactive "sQuery Replace in open Buffers: \nsquery with: ")
  (mapcar
   (lambda (x)
     (find-file x)
     (save-excursion
       (beginning-of-buffer)
       (query-replace arg1 arg2)))
   (delq
    nil
    (mapcar
     (lambda (x)
       (buffer-file-name x))
     (buffer-list)))))
```