# How to replace text in all open buffer when files are from very different directory?

Tags: emacs

How do I replace string across all open buffers in emacs?
I found this on internet but option 'Y' to change all buffers in one shot doesn't work and I need to change one buffer for  time with '!' option.

```
;; Query Replace in open Buffers
(defun query-replace-in-open-buffers (arg1 arg2)
  "query-replace in open files"
  (interactive "sQuery Replace in open Buffers: \nsquery with: ")
  (mapcar
   (lambda (x)
     (find-file x)
     (save-excursion
       (beginning-of-buffer)
       (query-replace arg1 arg2)))
   (delq
    nil
    (mapcar
     (lambda (x)
       (buffer-file-name x))
     (buffer-list)))))
```

Comment: A better duplicate (since it deals with replacing, not just searching): http://stackoverflow.com/q/7494203/729907

Comment: I'm sorry. It's really a duplicate question. Your link answers my question. Thanks

Comment: In that case, please consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just use `multi-occur-in-matching-buffers` and then press <kbd>e</kbd>
for `occur-edit-mode`. Then `query-replace` I guess. Finish off with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>. And don't forget to save all changed buffers.

Answer (score 0):

With [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview), Use `C-u C-c '` in *Icicle* mode.  That searches a subset you choose
 of the open buffers (or all of them).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137348/729907.